# Hyperlink the entire reference "Figure 1.2(a)" to the figure (no subfloats!)

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, hyperlink, autoref

I currently have some figures which are **single images** (no subfloats!) with multiple panels (a) and (b) like so:

[image]

Now, I'm currently cross-referencing such figures like so `Figure~\ref{fig:emotions}(a) and Figure~\ref{fig:emotions}(b)`. I am using the `hyperref` package, so hyperlinks are inserted like in the following image, where the red boxes indicate the locations of the hyperlinks to the figure:

[image]

However, I would like a command so I can write something like `\figureref[a]{fig:emotions} and \figureref[b]{fig:emotions}` which hyperlinks the entire reference text like so:

[image]

(The links are to Figure 1.2 as a whole, not the individual panels, but (a) and (b) are included in the hyperlinks.)

**How can I achieve this?**

When not referencing individual panels, I know I can use `hyperref`'s `\autoref` command to include "Figure" in the hyperlink, e.g. `\autoref{fig:emotions}` yields a hyperlinked "Figure 1.2" as desired when referencing the figure as a *whole*, but I can't include (a) or (b) in the hyperlink this way!

Comment: `\hyperref[fig:emoticons]{Figure~\ref*{fig:emoticons}(a)}` (untested as you didn't provide an example).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer that works, thanks! I defined a new command to make it convenient: `\newcommand{\figureref}[2][]{\hyperref[#2]{Figure~\ref*{#2}#1}}`